# How do I Spread out an array with possible empty slots?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, dynamic-arrays

I'm working with multi-dimesional arrays and am stumped trying to create a dynamic compatibility chart.

```
Given Data : 
4 instances of Value 1
7 instances of Value 2
```

**Ideal End Result Examples**

If there are 4 value 1's and 7 value 2's

```
[0] Value 2
[1] Value 1
[2] Value 2
[3] 
[4] Value 2
[5] Value 1
[6] Value 2
[7] 
[8] Value 2
[9] Value 1
[10] Value 2
[11] Value 1
[12] Value 2
```

If there are 4 value 1's and 4 value 2's (try to evenly space them out without overlapping)

```
[0] Value 1
[1] Value 2
[2]
[3] Value 1
[4] Value 2
[5]
[6] 
[7] Value 1
[8] Value 2
[9] 
[10] 
[11] Value 1
[12] Value 2
```

If there are 2 instances of 1 and three of 2.

```
[0] Value 1
[1] Value 2
[2]
[3] 
[4] 
[5]
[6] Value 2
[7] 
[8] 
[9] 
[10] 
[11] Value 1
[12] Value 2
```

I have bucket sizes of 12-24 for an array. In the example I use 12. If number of instances don't fit in 12 buckets, can move up all the way to 24. If it doesn't fit in 24, give an error.

Any loop that I've tried to make by using array_pop and reversing arrays creates empty holes in the middle of the array or it doesn't spread out the instances evenly.

---

Edit:
Here is what I've tried.

```
$table_array = range(0,12);
// Method 1 

for ($i = 0; sizeof($table_array); $i++)
{
    $ready_array[] = ($i % 2) ? array_pop($table_array) : array_shift($table_array);
}


// Method 2

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($table_array); $i++)
{
    $index = ($i % 2) ? sizeof($table_array) - ceil($i / 2) : ceil($i / 2);
    $ready_array[$index] = $table_array[$i];
}
ksort($ready_array);
```

**Project Details and Goal**

I have a list of compatible and incompatible pills.

I let the users select which pills and how many they're taking.

Based on that, I search the database and match up pills based on compatibility creating a lists known as Value 1 and Value 2.

I have a minimum 12 hour time frame to take the pills.

I'm supposed to space out lets say 4 of Calcium and 3 of Iron evenly across 12 hour period with 1 hour intervals and not let them overlap. If they choose 12 pills of Calcium and 12 pills of Iron, I can push up to 24 hours to make them take those pills.

Comment: check the if statements when loading the values.

Comment: Just to get it clear, the priorities are: `a`, `ab`, `aba`, `ababa`, etc (and doesn't matter if a is `Value 1` or `Value 2`)? What I mean by that: if possible left all values with one space in between (`a`); if not, add the least possible amount of `ab` (that is, two different values surrounded by space), and so on?

Comment: As above, please clarify the criteria for your algorithm, and also please show an example of your (failed) attempt

Comment: Added details, and sample code. Sample code creates holes in the middle or if I add more than 2 instances of each value, it doesn't spread out evenly.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas for your question :
Use `array_chunk()` and `array_count_values()`

```
<?php 

$myarray = array(2,1,2,'',2,1,2,'',2,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,'',2,1,2,'',2,1,2,1,2);
$tests = array_chunk($myarray, 13);
//print_r($tests);

function mytest($tests)
{
    foreach($tests as $test) 
    {
        // play your test !
        print_r(array_count_values($test));
    }    
}
// add your argument for your test
echo mytest($tests);
?>
```

output :

```
Array
(
    [2] => 6
    [1] => 5
    [] => 2
)
Array
(
    [2] => 7
    [1] => 4
    [] => 2
)
```

See for test : http://codepad.org/M9u5G0je